# extjs 5 parsing json in store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs5

I am using a reader in a store to parse a json response:

```
{    "results": 2, 
     "errors": "",
     "success": true,
     "data": [{
               "list": [{
                         "code": "123456",
                         "otherCode": "Y"
                         },
                         {"code": "369852",
                          "otherCode": "G"
                         }],
               "failedHost": false,
               "hostMessage": "",
               "hostReturnCode": 0
 }    ]}
```

And this is my store:

```
var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
        {

                proxy:
                    {
                      url: "myUrl",
                      reader:{
                               type: 'json',
                               rootProperty: 'list',
                               totalProperty: 'results'
                             },
                     type: 'ajax',
                     model: 'myModel'}}
```

The server is responding correctly but my store don't parse the response. The problem in my opinion is the deeper rootProperty, but I have found no solution.

Comment: Have you tried `rootProperty:'data.list'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rootProperty` needs to be:

```
rootProperty: 'data[0].list'
```

instead of:

```
rootProperty: 'list'
```